# Unit Test project giving Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core version error in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, xunit, asp.net-core-2.1

My Project Strcuture

Solution: LeaseManagement

Projects: LeaseManagement.Authenticate, LeaseManagement.UnitTest

Error (in LeaseManagement.UnitTest.proj):

Error   CS1705  Assembly 'LeaseManagement.Authentication' with identity 'LeaseManagement.Authentication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'    LeaseManagement.Tests

How to resolve this Error?

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved by just simply installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core -Version 2.1.1